# What does the sign() method of the "jsonwebtoken" module return in Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt

I can't find any good documentation online about `sign()` and `verify()` methods of the `jsonwebtoken` module. What do they return? What do they do?

```js
app.get('/token', (req, res) => {
    //route to get token
    let id = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 8);
    let limit = 60 * 3;
    let expires = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + limit;
    let payload = { 
        _id: id,
        exp: expires
    }
    let token = jwt.sign(payload, jwt_key);
    res.status(201).send({code: 0, message: 'ok', data: token});
})

app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    const header = req.header("Authorization");
    const [type, token] = header.split(" ");
    if(type === 'Bearer' && typeof token !== 'undefined') { 
        try{
           let payload = jwt.verify(token, jwt_key);
           let current = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000 );
           let diff = current - payload.exp;
           res.status(200).send({code: 0, message: `all good ${diff} remaining!`})
        }catch(err) { 
            res.status(401).send({code: 123, message: 'Invalid or expired token'});
        }
        
    } else { 
        res.status(401).send({code: 456, message: 'Invalid token'});
    }
})
```

The above snippet is obviously taken out of context, but what I don't get here is how does the `payload` variable in the second function, `app.get('/test', (req, res) => { .. }` has reference to the property defined in the `payload` object of the first function `app.get('/token', (req, res) => { .. }`?

I'm talking about this: `let diff = current - payload.exp;`
`payload` is defined in the same function, and `jwt.verify(token, jwt_key)` is assigned to it.
But how does this `payload` has access to the `exp` property defined in the `payload` object of the first function? The only explanation I can think of is if it has something to do with what `jwt.verify()` and `sign()` return.

Comment: https://jwt.io/ https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken

Comment: I saw this website, but there wasn't any explanation about what the sign() and verify() return.

Comment: The second link has a `Usage` section describing all functions.

Comment: `(Asynchronous) If a callback is supplied, the callback is called with the err or the JWT` what is that mean? What is the `JWT`? What does it mean `called with`? Does it mean it's passed? So what does it return then? `(Synchronous) Returns the JsonWebToken as string` .. what is JsonWebToken? Also, how does this explain my question related to the above snippet?

Comment: What a JsonWebToken is is explained in the first link. `Also, how does this explain my question related to the above snippet?` Your initial question was `what does sign and verify do`, and the links explains that. `But how does this payload has access to the exp property defined in the payload object of the first function?` Through the JWT.

Comment: Where is it explained in the link?

Comment: `Through the JWT` - HOW? Could you please explain it to me? The link says `sign()` returns a JWT string. So... the `token` variable is now assigned to a JWT string. So, this doesn't explain how does the second variable in the second function can access the property.

Comment: Look at the second function. Not only the `jwt.verify` line but all lines before aswell. Its pretty clear that the token comes from the `Authorization` header of the HTTP request.

Comment: The `tokens`, yes, but I am asking about this `payload.exp`. The second function defines a variable `payload`, and then has access to `exp` which is a JS object property defined in the `payload` of the first function. How does the second `payload` has access to the first `payload` object defined in the first function? The second function has `payload` as a variable assigned to `jwt.verify(token, jwt_key)`. How does this give the variable access to the `payload` object of the first function?

Comment: You should really _really_ read those links I provided. [JWT.io](https://jwt.io/) clearly states what an JWT is and that it contains an payload. [The library documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken) states that `jwt.sign` takes in the payload and returns the resulting JWT, also, `jwt.verify` returns the included payload. Since function 2 has access to the JWT generated in function 1, it has access to the payload (from `jwt.verify`).

Comment: If `jwt.verify()` returns a NEW payload, then again, how does it have access to the first payload object defined in the first function? I don't see the connection here. `Since function 2 has access to the JWT generated in function 1, it has access to the payload (from jwt.verify)` this part is UNCLEAR to me. You say it like it's `obvious` -- it's not. How exactly is this `connection` established? I don't see the connection. Could you elaborate on this connection more?

Comment: `If jwt.verify() returns a NEW payload,` It doesn't, it returns __the__ payload contained in your JWT.

Comment: So, this `jwt.verify(token, jwt_key)` returns this `payload = {  _id: id, exp: expires }`? How? Why? Obviously it's through the `token` argument, but where is the logic here? If `sign()` returns just a JWT string, how does `verify()` returns the object that was the first argument  of the `sign()` method? where's the connection here? This can't be true. You're saying that `token = jwt.sign(payload, jwt_key);` `token` is now a JWT string, but then `jwt.verify(token, jwt_key);` this returns reference to the `payload` object used in the first argument when assigning to `token`?

Comment: The JWT __contains__ the payload.

Comment: Yes, I already figured it out. Can I ask you one more thing, a bit unrelated. At the very beginning of the page where you usually get your modules, I have this `require('dotenv').config();`. I get that `config()` reads the `.env` file, parse the content, and assign it to `process.env`, but why is it not assigned to a variable like the rest of the modules? Why if I do this: `const something = require('dotenv')`, and then do this: `something.config()`, why is this not working? Why is it without a variable? Is it because `config()` automatically returns the object to `process.env`?